# haskell prelude : definition of seq

Tags: haskell

In the [definition of the haskell prelude](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) we see that `...` is reserved for expressions that cannot be implemented in Haskell. Now the `IO` monad for example can't be implemented in haskell.

What surprised me is that `seq` is defined as follows in the prelude

```
seq :: a -> b -> b
seq = ...       -- Primitive
```

Why not the following? what am i missing?

```
seq _ b = b
```

Answer (score 6):

As you can see in the [Haskell Wiki entry on `seq`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Seq), the `seq` function must fulfil the following two equations:

```
⊥ `seq` b = ⊥
a `seq` b = b
```

(where `⊥` is the undefined value, which is what non-terminating function applications or things like `hd []` and `undefined` evaluate to logically)

Your definition clearly does not fulfil the first equation.

The typical use case for `seq` is to force evaluation of the first parameter (to weak head normal form) before evaluating the second one. (although, strictly speaking, `seq` does not guarantee that; see again the wiki article)

Such a function is, to my knowledge, not definable in pure Haskell without any compiler extensions like `-XBangPatterns`.

Comment: BangPatterns are just an extension, they can/will be substituted by `case` statements with a single case.

Comment: Did I say they were not an extension? And by `case` statement, you mean in the GHC Core output? Yes, that is what I would expect to happen, but I still do not know of any way to achieve this in Haskell without using the built-in `seq`, or something like `BangPatterns`.

Comment: @sdx23 In general that's not true: a function-valued expression can not be forced by `case` in Haskell (unlike in GHC Core, where `case` does evaluate). You can define a `seq`-like function for all algebraic data types, by pattern matching against a constructor: for that `case` in indeed enough.

Comment: @ManuelEberl In plain lambda calculus, even when enriched with algebraic data types, you can't define `seq`. Otherwise, it wouldn't be a primitive. Theoretically, IIRC, some parametricity results are broken by `seq` but do hold in the LC, so ...

Comment: That's what I thought, but the Haskell standard is big and I don't know it that well. Anyway, `case` is also strict on tuples. `case undefined of (_, _) -> 42` will return ⊥. If one annotates the pattern match as irrefutable explicitly with `~`, it returns 42: `case undefined of ~(_, _) -> 42`.

Comment: what is the point of forcing the evaluation of the first parameter if the return value is ignored and its evaluation can't leave any side effects? (i am trying to learn)

Comment: @MichaelMoser, sometimes it's a lot cheaper (especially in terms of memory, but often also time) to perform a calculation immediately than to delay it until it's needed. The classic example is something using an accumulating argument to, e.g., sum a list. You want to actually add each number to the sum as you go, rather than building up a huge chain of things to sum later. `seq` is a way to do that. Bang patterns are, typically, a nicer one. The theoretical concerns chi mentioned get pretty annoying; I wish the Haskell designers had stuck to a more limited `seq`.